# JSP - How to call another JSP

Tags: html, jsp, jakarta-ee, netbeans

I have two web application which I have created using NetBeans 6.9.

Is it possible to make a call (HTTP request) from one web application's JSP page to other application's JSP page?
If so, then how?

Comment: What do you mean by call? An internal forward? An http redirect? Call a function defined on another JSP? Issue an http request to another resource?

Comment: I try to mean an http request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Jsp forward

> The jsp:forward action is used to permanently transfer processing from one JSP to another on the local server. Any content generated by the original page is discarded and the processing begins anew at the second JSP.

Answer (score 0):

Try the JSP:INCLUDE tag http://java.sun.com/products/jsp/tags/12/syntaxref1214.html

Answer (score 0):

try giving the http request throught url connection,, 
a Sun's example,,

```
URL yahoo = new URL("http://www.yahoo.com/");
URLConnection yc = yahoo.openConnection();
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(
                        yc.getInputStream()));
String inputLine;

while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) 
    System.out.println(inputLine);
in.close();
```

If you have to call the jsp with any parameters then attach them to the url as

```
URL yahoo = new URL("http://www.yahoo.com/login.jsp?uname=xxx&pass=yyyy");
```

or use [java.net.HttpUrlConnection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html)